# Delay sending an email via EWS leaves mail in sent-items without actually sending it

Tags: vba, ms-word, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm trying to delay-send an email through EWS (Exchange 2019) from a Word VBA module. This works fine, as long as I send immediately. As soon as I add the element for delayed send

```
<t:ExtendedProperty>
  <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="16367" PropertyType="SystemTime" />
  <t:Value>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</t:Value>
</t:ExtendedProperty>
```

The mail goes into sent items immediately and does not get delivered. This is the entire code - the XML is below for better readability:

```
Private Sub SendEMail()
  Dim sReq As String
  Dim xmlMethod As String
  Dim XMLreq As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
  Dim EWSEndPoint As String
  
  Dim t As String
  t = "2022-01-01T00:00:00.000"
  
  EWSEndPoint = "https://myexchange/EWS/Exchange.asmx"
  sReq = "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>" & vbCrLf & _
          "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=""http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"" xmlns:t=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"">" & vbCrLf & _
            "<soap:Header>" & vbCrLf & "<t:RequestServerVersion Version=""Exchange2016""/>" & vbCrLf & "</soap:Header>" & vbCrLf & _
            "<soap:Body>" & vbCrLf & _
              "<CreateItem MessageDisposition=""SendAndSaveCopy"" xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"">" & vbCrLf & _
                "<SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id=""sentitems"" />" & vbCrLf & _
                "</SavedItemFolderId>" & vbCrLf & _
                "<Items>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "<t:Message>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "<t:Subject>" & "123 " & Now() & " für " & t & "</t:Subject>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "<t:Body BodyType=""Text"">" & "body" & "</t:Body>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "<t:ExtendedProperty>" & vbCrLf & _
                      "<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag=""16367"" PropertyType=""SystemTime"" />" & vbCrLf & _
                      "<t:Value>" & t & "</t:Value>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "</t:ExtendedProperty>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "<t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf & _
                      "<t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf & "<t:EmailAddress>" & "myemail" & "</t:EmailAddress>" & vbCrLf & "</t:Mailbox>" & vbCrLf & _
                    "</t:ToRecipients>" & vbCrLf & _
                  "</t:Message>" & vbCrLf & _
                "</Items>" & vbCrLf & _
              "</CreateItem>" & vbCrLf & _
            "</soap:Body>" & vbCrLf & _
          "</soap:Envelope>" & vbCrLf

  xmlMethod = "POST"
  XMLreq.Open xmlMethod, EWSEndPoint, False, "myusername", "mypassword"
  XMLreq.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=""UTF-8"""
  XMLreq.Send sReq

  If XMLreq.Status = 200 Then
                    ' Message Sent okay
                    MsgBox ("ok")
  Else
                    ' Something went Wrong
                    MsgBox ("error")
  End If
End Sub
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<SavedItemFolderId>
<t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />
</SavedItemFolderId>
<Items>
<t:Message>
<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
<t:Subject>123 31.03.2021 13:35:19 für 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</t:Subject>
<t:Body BodyType="Text">body</t:Body>
<t:ExtendedProperty>
<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="16367" PropertyType="SystemTime" />
<t:Value>2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</t:Value>
</t:ExtendedProperty>
<t:ToRecipients>
<t:Mailbox>
<t:EmailAddress>myemail</t:EmailAddress>
</t:Mailbox>
</t:ToRecipients>
</t:Message>
</Items>
</CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I am in Europe here, so 24-hour-timeformat. To avoid any hazzle with time and date formatting, I have taken a simple day in the example, but that did not make any difference. I've tried past and future dates, no change: The mail goes to sent items immediately and does not send. (The xmlreq.send-lines always closes without error.) As soon as I remove the four extendedproperty-lines, it sends without problems.

What is it that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the SavedFolderId it's optional anyway but when i test your XML with it I see the same problem so

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
<soap:Header>
<t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2016"/>
</soap:Header>
<soap:Body>
<CreateItem MessageDisposition="SendAndSaveCopy" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
<Items>
<t:Message>
<t:ItemClass>IPM.Note</t:ItemClass>
<t:Subject>123 31.03.2021 13:35:19 für 2022-01-01T00:00:00.000</t:Subject>
<t:Body BodyType="Text">body</t:Body>
<t:ExtendedProperty>
<t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag="16367" PropertyType="SystemTime" />
<t:Value>2021-03-31T23:06:00.000</t:Value>
</t:ExtendedProperty>
<t:ToRecipients>
<t:Mailbox>
<t:EmailAddress>glenscales@yahoo.com</t:EmailAddress>
</t:Mailbox>
</t:ToRecipients>
</t:Message>
</Items>
</CreateItem>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

works okay for me, It does save the message temporary to the drafts folder (instead of the outbox) but once sent the message does end up in the SentItems Folder.

Comment: Thank you, Glen, it really works fine without the SavedFolderId. For the record: I have played a bit and left SavedFolderId in the XML and changed it to outbox. This put the messages in the outbox as expected, but future messages did not get delivered at all from there and messages with a past date did get delivered, but remained in the outbox. So I have now removed the code again and it works fine, although through drafts. If someone finds the source of this (cosmetic) error, I'll be entirely happy :-)